# Converting SQL query to Spark Data-frame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert the below query's to a spark data frame (I am pretty new to spark):

-- Creating group number

```
select distinct *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY person_id, trust_id) AS group_number;
```

-- This is what I got so far for above

```
df = self.spark.sql("select person_id, trust_id, insurance_id, amount, time_of_app, place_of_app from {}".format(self.tables['people']))

df = df.withColumn("group_number", dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy("person_id", "trust_id").OrderBy("person_id", "trust_id")))
```

-- Different query 1

```
where group_number in (select group_number from etl_table_people where code like 'H%') group by group_number having count(distinct amount) > 1;
```

-- Different query 2

```
where insurance_id = 'V94.12'
group by group_number having count(distinct amount) = 2;
```

Comment: Would you like to show any SparkSQL code?

Comment: This is what I got so far, but I am not sure if its correct: df =  df.withColumn("group_number", dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy("person_id", "trust_id").orderBy("
person_id", "trust_id")))

Comment: I would like it to be in a pyspark df, I am currently using the from pyspark.sql packages/libraries

Comment: Please edit your question to include formatted code. And pyspark.sql is the only way to create a dataframe. Why don't you print it to see if it's correct?

Comment: Also, you can type raw sql as well into Spark. You don't have to use any functions

Comment: Please show how you defined df to begin with

Comment: I edited the df to the code above, the goal is not to use raw sql but to use spark functions

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Window Spec Function of spark.

```
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("person_id","trust_id").orderBy(col("person_id").desc).orderBy(col("trust_id").desc)

df.withColumn("group_number", dense_rank() over windowSpec)
```

And you get your data frame using spark based on your Data Source. You can refer [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html) if your source is Hive

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any suggestions for the other two queries? That's what I am mainly confused on.